# iOS app stuck after push notification is received in UIApplicationStateInactive mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have this really simple flow, where a notification is received when the app is in killed mode and the user taps on that notification.

Logic will append two controllers to the array of current `viewControllers` in the `rootNavigationController`. So, if first view was the usual screen for my app, in this case it will be first>second>third.

If you open the app with the app-icon, you'll only see the first view.

Issue is, when you tap on the notification, third view has an async API call, which is invoked from `viewDidLoad`. The `SVProgressHUD` is used for ux purpose, which is hidden in the completion block of the API. Sometimes, the progressHUD keeps on rotating and nothing happens. It gets stuck, but If I set the breakpoint in the API call method itself, everything works fine every time.

Not able to figure out, how to debug this issue. Tried pausing the execution when it gets stuck, but no relevant thread seems to be in the list.

CODE in third VC:

```
- (void) fetchDataPoints
{
    //[SVProgressHUD show];

    [[ServerHandler sharedInstance]fetchDataFromServerWithApiUrlString:GET_ALL_DATAPOINTS methodType:@"GET" httpBodyData:nil contentType:nil otherHeaderFields:nil queryStringParams:nil withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSData *responseData, NSError *error, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,NSDictionary *responseDict)
     {
         [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

         if (success)
         {

         }
     }];
}
```

CODE: push notification

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive)
{
    ChildViewController *childList = ViewControllerWithSBID (@"DATASB",@"ChildScreenID");

    DetailViewController *detailVC = ViewControllerWithSBID(@"DATASB", @"DetailScreenID");

    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.rootNavigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

    [viewControllers addObjectsFromArray:@[childList,detailVC]];

    self.rootNavigationController.viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:viewControllers];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're starting and stopping the HUD on the main thread?

Comment: Please, can you post code where you show and dismiss HUD ?

Comment: are you sure theres nothing in VC2 that start/stops your progress hud ?

Comment: Even if I comment the code for showing the HUD, the API call never reaches the completion block unless I put a break point at the point where I call the API. Added the code